# Writing JSON schema for objects generated on values for a key in the JSON

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to write a JSON schema to validate the following JSON:

```
{
    "pour": [{
        "pourID": 814,
        "PourName": "A vs B"
    }
    .
    .
    .,
    {
        "pourID": 414,
        "PourName": "C vs D"
    }],
    "pourTime":{
        "814":{
            "attribute": "value",
            "attribute2": "value2"
        },
        .
        .
        .,
        "414":{
            "attribute": "value",
            "attribute2": "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

There can be n objects in the pour array and an object associated with each pourID under the pourTime object.

I have tried reading up related to dynamic values in JSON Schema, however, it seems like it wants me to declare an enum which is not possible in my case since the pourID is dynamically generated based on entries is database that are added by client

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it can't be done with the way your data is structured. JSON Schema can't reference data values other than the one being validated. That means the "pourTime" object can't use the value of the "pour" array to do it's validation. If you have control of the data structure, I'd recommend changing it.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a missing feature for JSON Schema implementation OR does my JSON structure not comply with the RFC for JSON?

Comment: It's an ongoing discussion on usage of "$data" keyword with reference - if I recall correctly, currently scheduled for review for draft-08 or later.